# Assigning data from a variable output argument list

Tags: function, matlab, arguments

Consider a function `varargout = foo(varargin)`. I know how to format a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html#br2js35-7) so we can generate `varargin` automatically. E.g. `[x y z] = ndgrid(-1:1,-1:1,-1:1)` is equivalent to:

```
inp = repmat({-1:1},[1 3]);
[x y z] = ndgrid(inp{:});
```

My question is: how do I obtain the *output* (`x,y,z` in the example) automatically? I.e.,

```
out = ndgrid(inp{:});
```

PS: I would like to avoid using `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this should work:

```
out = cell(size(inp));
[out{:}] = ndgrid(inp{:});
```